# Как реализовать очередь запросов?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

**Исходные данные**:

Есть проект, который использует методы из SDK стороннего проекта (асинхронные методы для работы с их сервером с параметром-колбэком) и содержит в себе Retrofit2 + OkHttp + Rx для работы с сервером напрямую. Для удобства используются лямбды.

**Задача**:

Необходимо, чтобы все запросы (и из SDK, и через Retrofit) выполнялись не чаще чем 5 раз в секунду, а если лимит превышен, выполнялись с задержкой.

**Вопрос**:

Как это реализовать? Первое, что приходит в голову - это Service + BroadcastReceiver. Но придется слушать ресивер в каждом активити/фрагменте, плюс получится не такая удобная реализация колбэков... Может быть можно это как-то реализовать с помощью Rx (в том числе обернув методы SDK), чтобы оставить лямбды для удобства?

Comment: Тоже интересно было бы узнать решение. Надеюсь привлечь внимание к этой теме.

Comment: Вы хотите асинхронные методы синхронизировать (с интервалом 1/5 секунды). Надо реализовать что-то вроде промежуточного таймера.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с подобной задачей. Вы нашли решение?

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать решение по этой теме. Если кто-то уже решил, дайте пожалуйста ответ.

Comment: Дак не проще вынести реализацию в отдельный класс с синхронизацией, чтобы любая активити питалась именно с этого класса.

Answer (score 1):

Может это поможет?

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(1000, 5000, 
 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
            public void call(Long aLong) {
                // here is the task that should repeat
            }
        });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49718536/10965132